# Finding sides of a triangle. Why does this work?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

My Question:

For the following problem, I know how to solve it, but I don't know why one of the steps works in solving it. That is the part where you use the Pythagorean theorem: $x^2 + x^2 = 25^2$

What do the x variables represent and why is a Pythagorean theorem being used on what appears to not be a right triangle?

Thanks for the help!

The Problem:

To estimate the height of a tree, one person stands due north of the tree and a second person stands due east of the tree. If the two people are the same distance from the tree and 25 feet from each other, find the height of the tree if the angle of elevation from the ground to the top of the tree at each person's position is 75°.

The Solution:

$$x^2 + x^2 = 25^2$$

$$x = 17.677$$

$$\tan(75)=\frac{h}{17.677}$$

$$h=66$$

Comment: Have you tried making a drawing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ is the distance on the ground from the tree to each observer.  There is a right triangle on the ground because one is north and one is east.  Then there is another right triangle for each person along the ground to the tree and vertically up the tree.  This is the one with the $75^\circ$ angle.  The leg along the ground is $x$